# In Python how to check if byte in UTF-8 bytearray is in ASCII a-zA-Z

Tags: python, performance

Assuming a UTF-8 bytearray how to check if an arbitrary individual byte is in the character range a-zA-Z knowing that these characters are represented by a single byte? Since these characters correspond the ASCII alphabetic character integer values are one byte in UTF-8 and any individual byte of a multibyte character will never match the integer value of one of these characters, it looks like checking the integer value of the byte is the fastest and safest.

This works for me, but is it the most efficient?

```
def isAsciiAlphaByte(c):
    return ((c>96 and c<123) or (c> 64 and c<91))

isAsciiAlphaByte(b"abc"[0])
>>> True
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, since UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding.

Comment: You can't test an individual byte in UTF-8.  Most non-ASCII codes require multiple bytes.

Comment: It sounds like he really just means ASCII not UTF-8.  The OP should really confirm this one way or the other.

Comment: @MarkTolonen It does make sense if you understand that ASCII alphabetic characters in UTF-8 are single bytes.

Comment: It makes sense now that you've clarified what you want.

Comment: Here is a test of an individual byte    b"abc123"[0] == 97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function looks like a faster solution - according to the timeit benchmark it is about 50% faster, according to cProfile benchmark it is about 40% faster. Either way ch(b).isalpha() is blazing fast and saves writing a separate function. So both work fine.

```
def isalphabyte(c):
   return ((c>96 and c<123) or (c> 64 and c<91))
a=bytearray(b"azAZ 123")
isalphabyte(a[0])
20: True
isalphabyte(a[4]) 
False

>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(1000000): chr(b"abc"[0]).isalpha()',number=1)
36: 0.31040439769414263
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(1000000): isalphabyte(b"abc"[0])',"from __main__ import isalphabyte",number=1)
37: 0.22895044913212814

>>> cProfile.run('for i in range(1000000): chr(b"abc"[0]).isalpha()')
         2000003 function calls in 0.571 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.364    0.364    0.571    0.571 <string>:1(<module>)
  1000000    0.156    0.000    0.156    0.000 {built-in method chr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.571    0.571 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1000000    0.051    0.000    0.051    0.000 {method 'isalpha' of 'str' objects}


>>> cProfile.run('for i in range(1000000): isalphabyte(b"abc"[0])')
         1000003 function calls in 0.335 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000000    0.133    0.000    0.133    0.000 <pyshell#74>:1(isalphabyte)
        1    0.202    0.202    0.335    0.335 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.335    0.335 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could call `.isalpha()` on the whole bytearray and its slices (including one byte slices):

```
>>> a = b"azAZ 123"
>>> b = bytearray(a)
>>> b.isalpha() # not all bytes in the array are ascii letters
False
>>> b[:4].isalpha() # but the first 4 bytes are alphabetic ([a-zA-Z])
True
>>> b[0:1].isalpha() # you need to use the slice notation even for a single byte
True
```

The above uses the fact that despite utf-8 being variable-width character encoding, *no* individual byte in a multibyte character belongs to ascii range for letters.

It also assumes that `.isalpha()` method for `bytearray` does not depend on locale e.g., `b"abа".isalpha()` is locale dependent in Python 2.

If you want to test an individual byte:

```
>>> from curses.ascii import isalpha
>>> b[0]
97
>>> isalpha(b[0]) # it accepts either integer (byte) or a string
True
```

Comment: Note: I accepted this answer but it is about 30-50% slower than the integral check I wrote in isAsciiAlphaByte. I am doing in-place editing of a UTF-8 document and only want to change certain ASCII values. Since they are always a single byte and never part of a multi-byte character I can do this.

Comment: I don't see in your benchmark the code from my answer so I don't understand what is slower than the code from your question (bytearray.isalpha should be faster because it works on many bytes , curses.ascii.isascii might be slower because it accepts both integers and characters (bytestrings)) If you want to replace individual bytes; try `bytearray.translate()` method

Comment: I put my benchmark in an answer I posted. The last answer listed here. I cannot do translate since not all characters are being replaced. Individual characters are being replaced as part of a recursive descent parsing of a document but the document does not conform to a regular grammar so using antlr or some other parser generator is not really an option. That is why I hand-crafted one for my specific purposes. It appeared to me to be a reasonable question for someone to ask.

Comment: yes. it is [the benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19263571/4279) I've meant. I don't see the code from my answer there. If you need to check only individual integers then your `isalphabyte()` is probably the fastest that you can get in pure Python if you can't somehow organize the input data to perform check on several bytes at once. About your question: I'm one of the two upvotes.

Comment: Thanks. The benchmark is not apples-to-apples. I will run it again. It was my first time using these benchmarking tools in python and I did not do much python up to now.

Comment: take a look at how [`reporttime.py` module is implemented and how it is used to compare peformance of several function that perform similar (or the same) task](https://gist.github.com/zed/4276624).

Comment: Thanks, will do. These down votes soured my drive and I gave up for several months. I am only doing this for fun in my spare time. I went off and learnt Scala instead and am trying to pick up Dart. But I wonder what the world would be like if the browser vendors bundled python. I am getting to like it but I prefered Ruby's Smalltalk message passing syntax. I think Larry Wall said copying pythons OO implementation was his biggest mistake...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to reduce a sequence down to a single value.  Here I am just applying a binary `and` after calling `str.isalpha` on every byte in the `bytearray`:

```
ba = bytearray('test data')
reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, (chr(b).isalpha() for b in ba))
```

But really

```
str(ba).isalpha()
```

would work just fine.

Comment: True, but I assume that is not the especially efficient...I will do some benchmarking.

Comment: Which one? I really doubt you'll beat `str(ba).isalpha()` with any other python code.

Comment: I think I just did...just use isalpha on the bytearray!

Comment: Nevermind.  Docs weren't clear on this.  Am withdrawing answer.

Comment: @MikeHousky Actually I didn't realize you could call `isalpha()` on a `bytearray`. Not sure why that wouldn't be correct here.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart See below...the bytearray doesn't use (doesn't remember, actually) the encoding.  There doesn't seem to be a definition of just what isalpha() does with non-ASCII codes on in a bytearray at docs.python.org, either.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, you don't test individual bytes...but you can use string methods directly on bytearray types, including isalpha():

```
>>> s = 'nowisthetime'
>>> b = bytearray(s, "UTF-8")
>>> b
bytearray(b'nowisthetime')
>>> b.isalpha()
True
```

Edited to add:  However, the isalpha() method doesn't seem to use the encoding to do per-character processing, so this seems to be ONLY good for ASCII alphabetics.  For example:

```
>>> b2 = bytearray("αβγ", "utf_8")
>>> b2.isalpha()
False
>>> str(b2,"utf_8")
'αβγ'
>>> str(b2,"utf_8").isalpha()
True
>>>
```

So, this may not be so hot if you really do need to know about other alphabets.  Oh well, it was faster, anyway... :(

PS: I used Idle/Python 3.3 for the above.  You will need to use u"" strings for the Greek letters in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, non-ASCII encodings, like UTF-8, are multibyte encodings. Which means you run into trouble. And here is how:

```
>>> x = bytearray("string","utf8")
>>> y = bytearray([x[0]],"utf8")
>>> print y
s
```

All looks good, but what happens if we aren't using all English letters.

```
>>> x = bytearray(u"touché","utf8")
>>> len(x)
7
```

Uh-oh..

```
>>> y = bytearray([x[-1]])
>>> print y
©
```

Well that isn't good.